# JUnit Test for file operations using PowerMock

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

```
public class FileUtil {

    public void methodOne(Bean bean) {
        StringBuffer profileControlValue = new StringBuffer();
        profileControlValue.append(bean.getName()).append(bean.getDesc());

        String sourcePath = "path to save";

        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sourcePath.toString())))) {

            writer.write(profileControlValue.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to write a Junit test case using Mockito/PowerMockito for above method.
Basically I have a method which accepts Bean and process the values and writes it into file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: I am new to JUnit testing, so not getting any directions for now to mock the above scenario

Comment: Can anybody please help me to have my test case for above method?